# A function that returns a list of letters, in the same order, except with any vowels appears as * and any l appearing as %

Tags: python, python-2.7

Write a function that takes a list of letters as an argument. The function should return a list of letters, in the same order, except with any vowels they appear as * and any L's appearing as %. Here is my solution, please tell me why it is not working:

```
lst [‘s’, ‘a’, ‘l’, ‘l’, ‘y’]

def letter_list(word):
newLetters = []
    for char in range(0, len(word) -1):
    if char in ‘aeiou’: 
        char = “ * “  
        if char.lower() == ‘l’  char = ‘%’ : 
          newLetters = newLetters + char
return newLetters

print letter_list(“Sally”)
```

Comment: Write a function that takes a list of integers as an argument. It should return True or False depending on whether there are any 2 integers in the argument list that sum to zero.  My answer is not correct..why?      lst = [4,3,2,6,-2,2]
def zero_sum(num):
    result = True
    for i in range(0, len(num) -1):
        result = num[i] + [num [i] +1] == 0
    return result
print zero_sum(lst)

Answer (score 0):

There is some ambiguity with your question and your solution. You are saying that the function will take the list of letters/chars, but you are sending the whole word.

Here is the solution:

```
def letter_list(word):
    newLetters = []
    for char in word:
        if char in "aeiou":
            char = "*"
        if char.lower() == 'l':
            char = '%'
        newLetters.append(char)
    return newLetters

# sending word as list of chars
print(letter_list(list("Sally")))
```

Comment: list of letters = iterable of chars,  a string = iterable of chars ? wheres the diff?

Comment: Yes. A string is iterable. I am just following the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def letter_list(word):
    newLetters = word.lower()
    newLetters = newLetters.replace("a", "*").replace("e", "*").replace("i", "*").replace("o", "*").replace("u", "*").replace("l", "%")
    return newLetters

print(letter_list("Sally"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work, because you use all the wrong markers for strings and chars. Beside that, you
:

- lack a `=` between `lst` and its vowels
- use `“` instead of `"`
- use `‘`and `’`  instead of `'`

and your indentation is wrong - you have to indent all things that belong inside your function (and you should indent consistently, not by 4 chars, then tabs, then 2 chars etc.)

Also you can use a comprehension:

```
def letter_list(word):
    return ''.join( c if c not in 'aeiou' else '*' for c in word).replace('l','%')
                    # use the character if not in aeiou else *  
                    # replace l after the fact                     

print(letter_list("Sally"))
```

Output:

```
S*%%y
```